# How to create multiple form for Excel

Tags: excel, forms

I was trying to make a Form entry with different kind of forms and difference input need to be filled. My initial idea is that by using a lot of drop box to make the form user friendly as much as I could

Here is some idea

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                     Form Selection Section                  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| Select a Form: [Form A]                                     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                             |
|                  Form A                                     |
| - Label 1: [Input Field 1]                                  |
| - Label 2: [Input Field 2]                                  |
| - ...                                                       |
| [Submit Button for Form A]                                  |
|                                                             |
```

If I choose form C, it will be

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                     Form Selection Section                  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| Select a Form: [Form C]   [Fill Form Button]                |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                             |
|                  Form C (Visible when selected)             |
| - Label 1: [Input Field 1]                                  |
| - Label 2: [Input Field 2]                                  | 
| - Label 3: [Input Field 3]                                  |
| - ...                                                       |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
```

Could you give me some Idea and guide on how to achieve this result?